# fluentd in http input json parser how to send multiple data in one point?

Tags: fluentd

according to json parser docs https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/parser_json

> The json parser plugin parses json logs. One JSON map, par line.

when sending one json at a time everything working fine:

```
$.post('<server_ip>/log',
        {json:JSON.stringify({
            "name":"test",
        })});
```

(i am using in_http source)

but when trying to send it a multipile points at once it always fail with

`400 Bad Request 757: unexpected token`

```
      $.post('<server_ip>/log',
      {
        json: JSON.stringify({
         "name": "test",
        }) + "\n" + JSON.stringify({
         "name": "test2",
        })
      });
```

edit:
the solution is:

```
$.post('<server_ip>/log','json=[{"name":"test"},{"name":"test2"}]');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use batch mode with default format: https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/in_http#batch-mode

Comment: totaly missed it :/ THANKS edited my question with the solution